# Spark-shell cannot read CSV file, failing with timeout in local mode

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-shell

```
spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.5.0

spark > val flightData2015 = spark.read.option("inferSchema", "true").option("header","true").csv("/Users/me/Desktop/2015-summary.csv")
```

**I am getting this exception**.

> java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /192.168.1.112:51351    at
>   org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:232)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:182)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.downloadClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:366)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.openChannel(NettyRpcEnv.scala:332)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.doFetchFile(Utils.scala:654)    at
>   org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.fetchFile(Utils.scala:480)   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:696)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies$5.apply(Executor.scala:688)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)  at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)    at
>   scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)    at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)  at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$updateDependencies(Executor.scala:688)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:308)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Operation
>   timed out: /192.168.1.112:51351   at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)  at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:257)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:291)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:631)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:566)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:480)
>     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
>     ... 1 more

Comment: I am not sure, I set this configuration spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "5") and it was working, but second time it again stopped working even with this configuration.

Comment: why are you using the databricks package  in your spark shell. it is not being used in you read command.  what version of spark you are running? what is your spark context looks like?  what is your master set as? post those things to the community. i think your syntax looks good to read CSV file

Comment: I am using spark version **spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7**. Databricks package is used to get the dependencies for reading CSV format, even If I use just **spark-shell** I am getting this error.  I am running spark in local standalone mode.